# What is the reason why isn't this code running properly in C?

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to learn C but my code is not running properly.It always gives fatal error.I think there is a problem in for loop.How can i fix it?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main( void )
{
   int a  ;
   int b = 1 ;
   int i = 0 ;
   printf("Enter a number:");
   scanf("%d",&a);

   if(a=0)
       printf("Factorial=1");

   else if (a > 0){
       for(i=1 ; i<=a ;i++){
       b = 1;
       b *= i; 
       }
       printf("Factorial=%d",b);
   }     
   else  
       printf("FATAL ERROR");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if(a=0)` should be replaced with `if(a==0`)

Comment: As @AditiRawat mentioned, `if (a=0)` is actually assigning `a` to the int `0`. Again, as Aditi mentioned, the correct comparison operator would be `==`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two major issues.
First being your use of `if(a=0)` which results in assignment in place of comparison which is achieved by `if(a==0)`.
Secondly

```
for(i=1 ; i<=a ;i++)
{
 b = 1;
 b *= i; 
}
```

This piece of code is faulty too. You are making `b=1` after every iteration which overwrites the intermediate results Hence resulting in incorrect answer. As you have already initialized `b` to 1 in your code, you do not need this line at all.

```
for(i=1 ; i<=a ;i++)
{  
     b *= i; 
}
```

Also it is worth mentioning that the reason you are always getting `fatal error` is because of what you are doing in the `if` condition. Due to `if(a=0)`, variable `a` is assigned value `0` . Hence not satisfying both `if` and `else if` conditions and resulting in the execution of `else` block every time.

Answer (score 2):

`if(a==0)` Not assignment use comparison.

You wanted to use the comparison but you ended up using assignment.

`if(a=0)` is same as `if(0)` so `else` part is executed.<sup>1</sup>

But that part also looks for `a>0` which is not the case.

So it prints `FATAL ERROR`.

<sup>1. This happens because the result of an assignment expression is the value of the expression</sup>

What do I need to do to calculate factorial?

```
fact(0)=1
fact(1)=1
fact(n)=n*fact(n-1);
```

so you will do something like

```
for(int i=1;i<=a;i++)
  b*=i;
```

You don't need that `b=1` part because it is making everything 1. So your calculated value is not retained.

So the complete corrected code will be

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int a;
   int b = 1 ;
   int i = 0 ;
   printf("Enter a number:");
   scanf("%d",&a);

   if(a=0)
       printf("Factorial=1");
   else if (a > 0){
       for(i=1 ; i<=a ;i++){
         b *= i; // don't overwrite value of b with 1
       }
       printf("Factorial=%d",b);
   }     
   else  
       printf("FATAL ERROR");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: @MuzafferTemelli.: If there is anything you didnt understand let me know